Ubuntu Desktop Guide contents not visible
Made a clean install of 24.04.
When I click on the [question mark] Help icon on the dock, the "Ubuntu Desktop Guide" loads, but nothing is visible. The files are there, I can print them, but I can't see them. When I move the cursor around it changes to the Black Hand and when I click, the title bar changes. Everything seems to be working, except...the files do not show.
